# How to deserialize a JSON to an object ignoring a key using Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson

Lets say I have a JSON:

```
{

"MovieCount": 153,
"MoviesList": [{...},{...},...]
}
```

I got:

```
mapper.readValue(moviesListArrayString, new TypeReference<List<Movie>>(){});
```

But that works when `moviesListArrayString` is:

```
[{...},{...},...]
```

if my *`String`* is the original JSON, how can I tell Jackson to ignore *`MovieCount`* and  deserialize *`MoviesList`*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution can be to read the full JSON as a JsonNode and only deserialize what you are interested in:

```
final JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(...);
movieList = mapper.readValue(node.get("MoviesList").traverse(), typeRefHere);
```

Comment: Depends from where you read. You said you had a `String` originally? Then just pass the string as an argument. `.readTree()` can also read from input streams, readers etc etc.

Answer (score 3):

I would create a wrapper object with two properties:

- `Number movieCount`
- `List<Movie> moviesList`

Then read the value as `YourWrapperObject.class` and do whatever you need to do with the `moviesList` property value, while ignoring the `moviecount` property.

**Quick, very ugly but functional example**

```
package test;

import java.util.List;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        String json = "{\"MovieCount\": 153,\"MoviesList\": [{},{}]}";
        try {
            List<Movie> movies = ((MovieWrapper) mapper.readValue(json, MovieWrapper.class)).moviesList;
            System.out.println(movies.size());
        }
        catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    static class MovieWrapper {

        @JsonProperty(value = "MovieCount")
        int movieCount;
        @JsonProperty(value = "MoviesList")
        List<Movie> moviesList;
    }

    static class Movie {

    }

}
```

**Output**

```
2
```

Comment: Thanks, @Mena I thought about it too, I'm sure deep in Jackson docs I can do so. For the moment I will go for your suggestion

Comment: @diegoaguilar you're welcome! Have fun with Jackson!

Comment: Yeah, What about Jersey, haven you given it an eye?

Comment: @diegoaguilar if you mean [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/), I haven't had the pleasure yet, no :)

Comment: Aha, I did a typo. Well, once I tried with it first but I completly forgot